# ajax file cannot upload file in php email form

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, html-email

I have problem with the ajax file. The ajax file does not work with the php form.
when I run the code it displays an error file_get_content error, file name empty.

The php code is working properly. but the ajax file cannot transfer the file field value.
So the file cannot attach with mail.

it shows the error: file name empty

plz help me to pass the file field value through the ajax file.

```
<div>
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"     action="contactus.php" onsubmit="xmlhttpPost('contactus.php', 'form1', 'Myresult', ''); return false;">
Name:<input name="name1" type="text"   value="" />
Address:<input name="address1" type="text"  value="" /> 
Phone:<input name="phone1" type="text" value=""/>
Email: <input name="email1" type="text" value="" />
File:<input name="file" type="file" size="35" id="file" />
Links:<input name="links1" type="text" value="" />
Subject:<input name="subject1" type="text" value="" />
Location:<select name="location">
              <option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>

Comments:<textarea name="comment1"  ></textarea>
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit"/>   
<div id="Myresult"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

php form(contactus.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 $name=$_POST['name1'];
$address=$_POST['address1'];
$phone=$_POST['phone1'];
$email=$_POST['email1'];
$subject=$_POST['subject1'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$comment=$_POST['comment1'];
$links=$_POST['links1'];

$to='mail@mail.com';

 $message .= "\nName: ".$name."\n\n";
 $message .= "Address: ".$address."\n\n";
 $message .= "Phone: ".$phone."\n\n";
 $message .= "Email: ".$email."\n\n";
  $message .= "Links: ".$links."\n\n";
  $message .= "Location: ".$location."\n\n";
  $message .= "Comments:\n\n ".$comment."\n";



$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];        
    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

$headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-To: $name <$email>";
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";


$message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

  --_1_$boundary
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

 --_2_$boundary
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 $message

 --_2_$boundary--
 --_1_$boundary
 Content-Type: $filetype; name=\"$filename\" 
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
 Content-Disposition: attachment 

 $attachment

 --_1_$boundary--";

 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

 print 'Thanks, your message sent!';

 }

 ?>
```

ajax.js

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL,formname,responsediv,responsemsg) {

var xmlHttpReq = false;

var self = this;

// Xhr per Mozilla/Safari/Ie7

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

}

// per tutte le altre versioni di IE

else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}

self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);

self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {

        // Quando pronta, visualizzo la risposta del form

        updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText,responsediv);

    }

    else{

        // In attesa della risposta del form visualizzo il msg di attesa

        updatepage(responsemsg,responsediv);



    }

}

  self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring(formname));

}



 function getquerystring(formname) {

 var form = document.forms[formname];

var qstr = "";



function GetElemValue(name, value) {

    qstr += (qstr.length > 0 ? "&" : "")

        + escape(name).replace(/\+/g, "%2B") + "="

        + escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\+/g, "%2B");

        //+ escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\n/g, "%0D");

}



var elemArray = form.elements;

for (var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++) {

    var element = elemArray[i];

    var elemType = element.type.toUpperCase();

    var elemName = element.name;

    if (elemName) {

        if (elemType == "TEXT"

                || elemType == "TEXTAREA"

                || elemType == "PASSWORD"

                || elemType == "BUTTON"

                || elemType == "RESET"

                || elemType == "SUBMIT"

                || elemType == "FILE"

                || elemType == "IMAGE"

                || elemType == "HIDDEN")

            GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);

        else if (elemType == "CHECKBOX" && element.checked)

            GetElemValue(elemName, 

                element.value ? element.value : "On");

        else if (elemType == "RADIO" && element.checked)

            GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);

        else if (elemType.indexOf("SELECT") != -1)

            for (var j = 0; j < element.options.length; j++) {

                var option = element.options[j];

                if (option.selected)

                    GetElemValue(elemName,

                        option.value ? option.value : option.text);

            }

    }

}

return qstr;

}

function updatepage(str,responsediv){


document.getElementById(responsediv).innerHTML = str;


}
```

Comment: I think you should use jQuery `. serialize` for serializing  form data for ajax why dont you use `.ajax` for that? check these [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 1):

problems:

1) Standard AJAX cannot upload files. The usual workaround is to build a form in a hidden `<iframe>` and perform a standard POST upload there.

2) Your code simply ASSUMES an upload has been performed **AND** succeeded. This is, frankly, stupid. **NEVER** assume success when dealing with users. Always prepare for the worst. Your code, at minimum, should have something like this:

```
if ($_FILES['fieldname']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("File upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['fieldname']['error']);
}
```

if you'd had something like that, you'd have gotten (probably) error code #4 - no file uploaded, because uploads cannot be done via AJAX. The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

3) You are building your own mime emails, which is not the easiest thing to get right. Why don't you try using Swiftmailer or PHPMailer? Both make sending a MIME email, with html, embedded attachments, etc... almost trivial. Virtually all of your MIME-building code would be reduced to a **SINGLE** line in either library.

Comment: it shows the file_get_content error, file name empty. I think the ajax file cannot pass the file field value to the php file.
how can i upload file to the email php form. other all fields are passed through this ajax file. the file field cannot attach with the emai form, it shows the file name empty error.

Comment: exactly. you cannot NOT upload files via ajax. therefore you will NEVER "get" a filename in PHP, because no file will ever be uploaded. you need to use workaround I mentioned in point 1)